# Bing Speech API just stops responding

Tags: android, speech, bing, azure-cognitive-services

I noticed somebody else asked essentially the same question, but received no replies.

I am using the Bing Speech API in an Android app. I'm basically using one of the provided examples for continuous recognition.

My app works great, and recognition is really good, but after about 1 1/2 minutes or so the Bing Speech API just stops responding.

I put debug statements in my code. Everything in my code is working as it does when successful.

When the Bing Speech API stops responding, I don't receive a FinalResponse callback message – no Error callbacks, nothing.

It's as if the Bing Speech API session just times out – and doesn't tell anybody.

Has anyone experienced this? Is there some notification that I'm not checking for?

Is there any documentation for this API?

Barry.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on a free trial subscription I image you have hit the per second/minute API rate limit.  This is from the documentation.  I assume you on a trial are since you mentioned using their examples.

> Trials have both rate limit, in terms of transactions per second or minute, and a monthly usage cap. A transaction is simply an API call. You can upgrade to paid tiers to unlock the restrictions.

Source: https://www.microsoft.com/cognitive-services/en-us/documentation

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Yes, I am still testing on a free trial.
I am the only one using this free trial account and key.

The transactions per time limit does not make sense.

It stops responding after approximately the same amount of time whether I am silent for the 30 to 60 second time period leading up to when it stops responding or if I'm saying phrases like "Mary had a Little Lamb" once every five seconds or so up to this no-response period.

I should not be anywhere close to the monthly maximum transactions – I am the only user and I am still just testing.

Comment: If I reinitialize the dataClient in my software it starts working again. This confirms that the monthly maximum limit is not the culprit.

Comment: Do you get any kind of response from the server at all?  An HTTP status with an empty body even?  Remember the limits aren't just per month, but also per second and per minute.  Hope you get it figured out!

Comment: Thanks. No responses from the server. I can't believe it's a limit since there is only one user, not anywhere near the monthly limit and only two or three accesses per minute. I rearranged my code to make sure the dataClient is always fresh. I haven't tested enough to see if this helps. Strange that it just stopped working with no error indications or anything.

Comment: Did you figure this out @BarryS? I have the same problem now. I am trying to enable continuous speech recognition, but it stops, just like you are experiencing :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not been able to figure this out for continuous speech recognition. I returned to something similar to their noncontinuous speech, built-in mic recognition, example. It also just stops responding, but is implicitly reinitialized on each use, so seems more reliable.